# Proving a metric is non-complete

Tags: real-analysis

I know that to prove a metric space not to be complete I just need to find a counterexample where a series is Cauchy in the metric that doesn't converge in it. However, I can't figure out how to do it with this somewhat difficult to manpulate metric (given to the real numbers):

$$ d(x,y) = \left| \frac{x}{1+|x|}-\frac{y}{1+|y|}\right| $$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The function

$$f:\Bbb R\to(-1,1):x\mapsto\frac{x}{1+|x|}$$

is a homeomorphism, and $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$ is just the usual Euclidean distance between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ in $(0,1)$. Find a Cauchy sequence in $(-1,1)$ that does not converge to any point of $(-1,1)$, and use $f$ to ‘pull it back’ to a sequence in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: this is my question: how can I find such a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: @boudreaux: What about a sequence in $(-1,1)$ that converges to $1$ in $\Bbb R$? $1\notin(-1,1)$, so that sequence doesn’t converge in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm just a little confused about where the interval (-1, 1) is coming from.

Comment: @boudreaux: It’s the image of $\Bbb R$ under the homeomorphism $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe the behaviour of the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{1 + |x|}$. As $x \to \infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)$ will get closer and closer to $1$. Intuitively, the metric will squeeze things together for you as you move to the right on the real line, in the sense that $1000, 1000+1$ are much closer than $1, 1+1$ under this metric.

To exploit this, consider the sequence $a_n = n$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then note that for $N$ large enough, you can have $1 - \epsilon < f(a_N) < 1$. Then, observe that for any $a_m, m \ge N$, you will also have $1 - \epsilon < f(a_m) < 1$, which means that if $n, m \ge N$, $f(a_n)$ and $f(a_m)$ lie in the same interval $(1-\epsilon, 1)$, which implies $|f(a_n )- f(a_m)| < \epsilon$. So the sequence is Cauchy. Next, you show that this sequence does not have a limit point, hence does not converge. Then you are done!